# NetSuite Service Login with SessionID (can not retrieve sessionID from current service) in C#

Tags: c#, web-services, session, netsuite

For the life of me I can no figure out where to get the SessionID out of the service so that I can use it in a future call to recreate the same session.

I am currently using the 2013_1_0 version of the wsdl in C#

When referencing the older documents [SuiteTalkWebServicesPlatformGuide_2011.1.pdf](http://www.netsuite.com/portal/partners/integration/download/SuiteTalkWebServicesPlatformGuide_2011.1.pdf) on page 78 (Reusing Session IDs During Login) they talk about this.

Any Suggestions?

Here is my sample code for logging into NetSuite without using a previous SessionID...

```
            // invoke the login operation
            Passport passport = new Passport();
            passport.account = _sNetSuiteAccount;
            passport.email = _sNetSuiteUserName;
            RecordRef role = new RecordRef();
            role.externalId = _sNetSuiteRole;
            passport.role = role;
            passport.password = _sNetSuitePassword;
            status = service.login(passport).status;

            // Confirm login was a success
            // Process response
            if (status.isSuccess == true)
            {
                _bIsNetSuiteAuthenticated = true;
            }
```

Additionally I have yet to find sample code for using the SessionID to re-create the service.  So any suggestion there would also be welcomed.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you had any luck solving this?

Answer (score 0):

In talking with NetSuite what I desire to do is impossible and the SessionID is stored as a private variable and handled by the .NET code.
I am currently seeking an alternative to a persistent session so when code base is called multiple times that the user will not need to be prompted for each iteration to enter their NetSuite cridentials.  I will update this answer as more details come available on this.